# Three.js - removing object (.obj) with scene.getObjectByName()

Tags: javascript, three.js

For my game, I am loading 4 different objects (buildings) and cloning each of them 15 times in a `for` loop. I add each clone to a `masterBuildingArray` array which I then loop through with a `forEach` loop. Each building is loaded using the `.MTL` and `.OBJ` Loaders.

The buildings are for a city and so I first randomise the order of the buildings in the array using an algorithm, and then, using `if` statements, set the position of every 10 buildings so that they are lined up in 3 rows on either side of a central road.

**My Problem**

I want to be able to remove any object from this array as I have some special (landmark) buildings that need to replace specific buildings in the array (basically they need to be in certain positions). I know that for example the building that is closest to the camera on the right side (i.e. bottom left of the 3x10 grid of buildings on the right side of the central road) has a position of roughly `(550, -75, 800)`. The `X` and `Z` positions are slightly randomised hence "roughly".

***My code is at the bottom of the question***

**My Ideas**

I added an index counter to my `forEach` loop which I then also assign to each building as `userData` so that I can access each building. My idea was to add an `if` statement to the `forEach` loop which looks like the following:

```
if (highriseBuilding.userData.index == 31) {
    initialBuildingName = highriseBuilding.name;
    highriseBuilding.name = highriseBuilding.name + "_toBeRemoved";
}
```

I would add the string `"_toBeRemoved"` to the name of the building in which is in the position I want removed and then somehow remove that object.

I thought I could then simply remove it with the following:

```
scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName(initialBuildingName + "_toBeRemoved"));
```

However this did not work no matter where I placed it (inside the initial `forEach` loop, in it's own separate `forEach` loop that ran through the `masterBuildingArray` after the first loop etc...)

**Here's my code:**

*Example of how a building is loaded:*

```
function createHighrise4() {

var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
        console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
    }
};

var onError = function ( xhr ) { };
THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader(loadingManager) );
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader(loadingManager);
mtlLoader.setPath( '/objects/highrise4_white_curved/' );

mtlLoader.load( 'highrise4_white_curved.mtl', function( materials ) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader(loadingManager);

    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( '/objects/highrise4_white_curved/' );

    objLoader.load( 'highrise4_white_curved.obj', function ( highrise4_white_curved ) {

        highrise4_white_curved.scale.set(10,10,10);

        highrise4_white_curved.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                    child.castShadow = true;
                }
            } );

        for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

            clonedHighrise4 = highrise4_white_curved.clone();
            clonedHighrise4.name = "highrise4_white_curved";
            masterBuildingArray.push(clonedHighrise4);

        }

    }, onProgress, onError );

});

}
```

*How each building is placed + my attempted solution:*

```
function loopThroughBuildingArray() {

randomShuffle(masterBuildingArray);

masterBuildingArray.forEach(function(highriseBuilding, i){

    let building_randomYScale = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 10) + 10);
    highriseBuilding.userData.index = i;

    if (i < 10) {
        rowLeft1.push(highriseBuilding);
        highriseBuilding.position.z = Math.floor(Math.random() * (950 - 850) + 850);
        highriseBuilding.position.x = incrementLeft1;
        incrementLeft1 -= Math.floor(Math.random() * (800 - 550) + 550);
    }
    if (i >= 10 && i < 20) {
        rowLeft2.push(highriseBuilding);
        highriseBuilding.position.z = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - -50) + -50);
        highriseBuilding.position.x = incrementLeft2;
        incrementLeft2 -= Math.floor(Math.random() * (800 - 550) + 550);
    }
    if (i >= 20 && i < 30) {
        rowLeft3.push(highriseBuilding);
        highriseBuilding.position.z = Math.floor(Math.random() * (-950 - -850) + -850);
        highriseBuilding.position.x = incrementLeft3;
        incrementLeft3 -= Math.floor(Math.random() * (800 - 550) + 550);
    }
    if (i >= 30 && i < 40) {
        rowRight1.push(highriseBuilding);
        highriseBuilding.position.z = Math.floor(Math.random() * (950 - 850) + 850);
        highriseBuilding.position.x = incrementRight1;
        incrementRight1 += Math.floor(Math.random() * (800 - 550) + 550);
    }
    if (i >= 40 && i < 50) {
        rowRight2.push(highriseBuilding);
        highriseBuilding.position.z = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - -50) + -50);
        highriseBuilding.position.x = incrementRight2;
        incrementRight2 += Math.floor(Math.random() * (800 - 550) + 550);
    }
    if (i >= 50 && i < 60) {
        rowRight3.push(highriseBuilding);
        highriseBuilding.position.z = Math.floor(Math.random() * (-950 - -850) + -850);
        highriseBuilding.position.x = incrementRight3;
        incrementRight3 += Math.floor(Math.random() * (800 - 550) + 550);
    }
    // 31 is building in position: right side, bottom left corner (closest to camera & road on right side)

    if (highriseBuilding.userData.index == 31) {
        initialBuildingName = highriseBuilding.name;
        highriseBuilding.name = highriseBuilding.name + "_toBeRemoved";

    }

    highriseBuilding.scale.y = building_randomYScale;
    highriseBuilding.position.y = -75;
//        highriseBuilding.position.y = (highriseBuildingBoundingBox.max.y * highriseBuilding.scale.y) / 2;


    cityScape.add(highriseBuilding);

});

cityScape.position.z = -9300;
cityScape.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
scene.add(cityScape);
scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName(initialBuildingName + "_toBeRemoved"));
}
```

I would really appreciate any help as I am completely stuck on how to do something I thought would be simple!

Answer (score 0):

Default name of any three object is an empty string. scene.getObjectByName returns the first object which has the given name. So `scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName(initialBuildingName + "_toBeRemoved"));` will always return the first object, since all buildings that you added to the scene will have same name "*_toBeRemoved*". Try giving unique name to each building.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not all buildings have that name. Only the building that has the index of 31 in this case has that name. I can also confirm this by console logging the name of each building in the `masterBuildingArray`, which shows only one has this name.

Comment: are you able to get the object that needs to be removed with `scene.getObjectByName(initialBuildingName + "_toBeRemoved")`?

Comment: yes if I do `console.log(scene.getObjectByName(initialBuildingName + "_toBeRemoved"));` I get the object's info in the console

Comment: Did you try rendering the scene after removing the object?
Can you check number of objects in scene before and after removing the object?
Also it would be helpful if you can create a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Number of objects stays the same when I remove it from the scene. I'm not able to create a fiddle for this project but happy to give any more detail. Could the problem be that the object returned by `scene.getObjectByName(initialBuildingName + "_toBeRemoved")` is a group and has the `Mesh` as a child?

Comment: Also I can see it physically isn't being removed

Comment: One possiblity is, the actual object that needs to be removed is the parent of the object returned by `scene.getObjectByName(initialBuildingName + "_toBeRemoved")`. So you can try removing its parent.

Comment: The parent of the object returned by that is the array with all the buildings in, removing that would result in all buildings being removed

Comment: Are you rendering the scene after removing the object? Can you please confirm , if removing the parent is removing all the buildings?

Comment: I am yes, I have a render loop running for animations and so the scene is rendered every frame (I assume this is what you mean, if not and I have to render the scene in some other way when removing an object, maybe that is my issue but I don't think so). I can confirm removing the objects parent successfully removes the whole array (all buildings)

Comment: Removing the parent works and successfully removes it as I said so I assume that shows that I do render the scene after the object is removed

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log` or `debugger`? It's also javascript, so you don't have to overload that string, you can put any kind of property anywhere at any time. `highriseBuilding.shouldIRemoveThis = true` <- for example